# Detail Slide Out On Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to know if there is a jQuery plugin that does something similar to the effect you get you hover these images http://bufferapp.com/extras, looks like a little drawer sliding up, I'd like to know what is the best solution—need it for a project.

I started to work on my own version of it ([here's the demo so far](http://f.cl.ly/items/13191t1d2j092r0N3f1z/Screen%20Recording.mov)), it's going well still testing it... but I can't seem to find a plugin ready made, maybe I'm not looking for the right thing, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Show](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/)/[Hide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/) of [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home). In the demo for `show`/`hide` the action is for button [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) ... instead of that you have to use something like [.mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).